# Lightbox /other JavaScript library conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have the following code in the header of a website that I'm working on but they both seem to be in conflict with each other.

```
<link href="tq.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script src="framework/mootools.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="slideshow/js/slideshow.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="slideshow/js/slideshow.kenburns.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="slideshow/css/slideshow.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="js/prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/scriptaculous.js?load=effects" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/lightbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The Sideshow stops working whenever I add the lines below while the lightbox works. How can I fix it?

```
<script src="js/prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/scriptaculous.js?load=effects" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/lightbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: is the lightbox a jQuery plugin? Do you have jQuery somewhere as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery `noConflict`. Information about which can be found at: http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries

Comment: The noConflict method helped

Comment: if it solved your problem, please mark the answer as correct and help community :)